# What is the Pipewire alternative to the switch-on-port-available Pulseaudio module?

Tags: linux, audio, pulse-audio, pipewire

I just set up Pipewire on my system, but there is one thing that bugs me: when I turn off my external DAC, and then turn it back on, Pipewire will not reconnect to it. With Pulseaudio, this issue could be resolved by loading `module-switch-on-port-available`. [According to the Pipewire Gitlab page](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Migrate-PulseAudio#modules-1), there is an alternative to this functionality though the
session manager, however, I have not been able to find out what this alternative is.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure if this solution replicates the old behavior exactly, it manages to switch the output to my DAC whenever I turn it on, so I am considering it as a solution to my question.

locate your `pipewire-pulse.conf` file. Mine is in `~/.config/pipewire`, but yours could be located elsewhere. You will see the following:

```
pulse.cmd = [
    { cmd = "load-module" args = "module-always-sink" flags = [ ] }
    #{ cmd = "load-module" args = "module-switch-on-connect" }
    #{ cmd = "load-module" args = "module-gsettings" flags = [ "nofail" ] }
]
```

Uncomment  the line `#{ cmd = "load-module" args = "module-switch-on-connect" }`, then save the file and restart pipewire. On my non-systemd system (MX Linux) this is done by killing the `pipewire`, `pipewire-pulse`, and `wireplumber` processes, then running `sudo pipewire-start &`. On systemd you can restart pipewire like any other service.

Comment: I probably did something wrong, but adding this to ubuntu-23.10 caused tons of delays and slow-down, most apps were unstable (including `gnome-terminal-server`). I'll come back if I find how to get this to work.